# How to test Model Errors with Mocha and rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, mocha.js, rails-models

I have this problem related to testing model errors with Mocha:

1. This is my controller (Api / Artist controller):

   ```
   class Api::ArtistsController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json

      def create
        artist = Artist.new(params[:artist])
        if artist.save <-- This is where the test fails
          render :json=>artist
        else
          respond_with artist
        end
      end
   end
   ```
2. This is my model (Artist Model):

   ```
   class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
      include Core::BaseModel
      attr_accessible :name
      has_many :albums
      validates :name, :presence=>true, :uniqueness=>{:case_sensitive=> false}
      default_scope where :deleted=>false
   end
   ```
3. This is the test where it fails, about Artist controller:

   ```
   it "should not save a duplicated artist" do
     Artist.any_instance.stubs(:is_valid?).returns(false)
     Artist.any_instance.stubs(:errors).returns({:name=>[I18n.t('activerecord.errors.messages.taken')]})
     post :create, :format => :json

     expect(response).not_to be_success
     expect(response.code).to eq("422")

     results = JSON.parse(response.body)
     expect(results).to include({
         "errors"=>{
           "name"=>[I18n.t('activerecord.errors.messages.taken')]
         }
       })
   end
   ```

When I run the tests, this is the error I get on the above test:

```
Failure/Error: post :create, :format => :json
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `add_on_blank' for {}:Hash
     # ./app/controllers/api/artists_controller.rb:17:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/api/artists_controller_spec.rb:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm starting to use Mocha, so I don't know if there's a way to test the json result for the specific case when I want to test the validation for the duplicated name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Base#errors` (i.e. `Artist#errors`) isn't a simple hash.  It's supposed to be an instance of `ActiveModel::Errors`.  You're stubbing it with a hash, and ActiveRecord is trying to call `add_on_blank` on it, which is failing.

I don't think `save` invokes `is_valid?` at all, and I suspect it's running the validations and then trying to call `add_on_blank` to append an error, but since you've stubbed out `errors`, that's failing.

This isn't really a good way to test the controller.  It's making too many assumptions about the internals of `Artist`.  You're also testing things that aren't part of the controller at all; `errors` isn't referenced anywhere in the action.  The only behavior worth testing in the controller is whether or not it creates an `Artist`; if that `Artist` fails to save, that it renders JSON with it; and if the save succeeds, that it redirects.  That's all of the controller's responsibility.

If you want to test that errors are rendered a certain way, you should write a separate view spec.  If you want to test that missing fields generate errors, you should write a model spec.  If you don't want to write a view spec, it's still sufficient to rely on the model to populate `errors` (tested in a model spec), and in your controller, just test that `render` is called with `json` set to the `Artist` instance.

Generally speaking it's best to avoid stubbing as much as possible, but in this case, the only things I'd consider stubbing are `Artist.new` to return a mock, and `save` on that mock to return false.  Then I'd check to make sure it rendered with the mock.

The easier option is to just create an actual `Artist` record, then call `post` with duplicate params to trigger a validation  failure.  The downside is that you hit the database, and avoiding that in a controller spec is laudable, but generally more convenient.  You could instead do that in a Capybara feature spec if you want to avoid DB hits in your controller specs.

If you want to try testing the way you are, you can manually create an instance of `ActiveModel::Errors` and populate that, or stub methods on it, and stub out `Artist.any_instance.stubs(:errors)` to return your mock with `ActiveModel::Errors`-compatible behavior, but that's a lot of mocking.

One final tip:  don't use `post :create, :format => :json`.  Use `xhr :post, :create` to generate a real Ajax request rather than relying on a `format` param.  It's a more robust test of your routing and response code.

Comment: How "you shouldn't do it" is answering the question?